# Why do most audio players skip the first second on first playback?

Tags: audio, low-power

I'm unsure where to ask this question really, since it seems to span a number of discipline, including electronics and software engineering.

Since I noticed this behaviour on devices with very limited software, I'm tempted to assume it's an electrical design thing.

**A bit of context:**

I've noticed that most audio players tend to skip the first second (or so) of music when first started. This is a behaviour I've noticed in the recent years (probably the last 3-4 years).

Example scenario:

- Boot up the device
- Start up an audio player
- Play a song

Almost invariably, the first second of the song will be skipped. Now, **if you play it again from the start, that missing second will appear**.

I've noticed this behaviour on a number of devices:

- macbook
- iphone
- ipad
- android phones
- small mp3 players
- windows machine
- another feature phone, the CAT B100

I've also noticed that this behavior appears with almost any software:

- itunes
- spotify
- vlc
- you-name-it

Also, I tried with various earphones and speakers.

This is actually driving me nuts, since it kinda "breaks" the music. I'm quite sensitive to that, so I'd like to understand, and maybe solve, the issue.

**And here comes the question:**

This issues doesn't seem to be linked to any particular software or hardware. **What's the link?** I suspect a kind of battery saving strategy, which would initialise the sound device too late. Is there a known pattern for that kind of thing?

As a software engineer, can I work around this?

Comment: I've never noticed this. And I can't reproduce. Neither on my android smart phone, nor my archos jukebox, nor a 5€ MP3 player, nor the mp3 player on my old nokia phone, nor my discman. I don't have a running windows machine, but I 100% guarantee my Linux audio subsystem doesn't do that. So, I'm tempted to close as irreproducible? Maybe there's a common denominator in your system that I don't have. Are you perhaps connecting all these to an external amplifier? Some wireless audio transport? Something else?

Comment: What I **am**, however, very familiar with, is Tinnitus, which if I usually ignore, which might psychoacoustically "mask out" sounds until I've realized they're actually there. But a second seems to long for that...

Comment: Never noticed it either, just opened iTunes on my Windows 7 laptop and played a song to make sure and it started straight away at the beginning.

Comment: Well I'm positive I have the issue. Probably not all the time, but it does exist. No tinnitus so far (fingers crossed!). But ok, maybe the problem lies elsewhere. Thanks for your input.

Comment: this behavior was existing on my first portable CD player (Sony discman). It would buffer songs for 3 seconds prior playing them. Disc player are quite sensitive to shocks. So in case of a shock the song would keep playing even though no data was read from the disk at the time. Maybe the buffering was kept for some audio system to recover from issues in the digital to analog audio conversion and guarantee uninterrupted experience.

Comment: I also have a Soundbridge at home connected to a DLNA server on a NAS device and I've never noticed it on that either. Though it sometimes takes a while to start playing a track if the disks have spun down after a period of inactivity.

Comment: @HervéGrabas but as far as I understand, your discman never *skipped* the first seconds, it just made you *wait*...

Comment: There is loudspeaker "anti-thump", which turns on speakers slowly; I don't know whether these devices do it with headphones, though.

Comment: @pjc50 that might be an explanation! The effect usually kicks in when the sound device is off (as in, there doesn't seem to be any current in the speakers).

Comment: @HervéGrabas indeed I remember the shock buffering, but as Marcus pointed out, there was nothing lost, only added latency. (It was an amazing feature at the time though :) )

Comment: sounds like fully-drained caps sucking up inrush current. i blame power management. i suspect caps because my sub-woofer does this after it self-powers down.

Answer (score 2):

I, like others in the comments, have never noticed or been able to reproduce this behavior.

The only likely explanation I can think of is it's your speakers or whatever you are using to listen, not your music player. Some amplifiers might have an audio detection circuit to automatically go into a low power mode when nothing is playing. To reduce false positives it waits for a second of music before turning on. The turn on may also take noticeable time: usually this is done to avoid a loud and potentially damaging "thump" as the amplifier voltages ramp up.